# Can I change a ports for existing Memgraph docker container?

Tags: docker, memgraphdb

I have run a Memgraph Platform using `docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 --name project1 memgraph/memgraph-platform`. Now I want to spin up a new instance of Memgraph using `docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 --name project2 memgraph/memgraph-platform`.

I get this error, and I get why do I get it.

`docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint project2 (fb3287cdaeee514ff9191f26891a57d7d77201184aab0dec2adc9de569efcfc9): Bind for 0.0.0.0:7687 failed: port is already allocated.`

The thing is that I need to use ports `-p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000` for `project2`. Is there a way to change port mapping for existing container `project1`?

I run project1 using `docker start project1`. Can I add some flags to change port mappings? I couldn't find option for that in Docker desktop. Maybe it can be done in CLI?

[Docker ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcBWT.png)

Comment: Stop and delete the existing container, and recreate it with different port options.